# Custom ol li indent

Tags: html, css

I found some topics related to this issue but none of them helped me.

How can I fix that the second line of the li respects the indent as it does the first line?
[image]

```
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
  margin: 1rem 0.25rem;
  line-height: normal;
}


ol li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 24px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
 }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving negative margin to pseudo element and a padding-left to the li as shown in code:

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
  margin: 1rem 0.25rem;
  line-height: normal;
  padding-left: 3rem;
}

ol li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 24px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-left: -3rem;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>abv asfbakjh dslsjdgljs lsgljgklj ljsdgll lslgklsdljlsdjgjksd lljljkj hghjgjhgjhgjhjg gjhghjsdf . dgdsg dfg fgsdfsg fg dsfgsf sdfg</li>
  <li>abv asfbakjh dslsjdgljs lsgljgklj ljsdgll lslgklsdljlsdjgjksd lljljkj hghjgjhgjhgjhjg gjhghjsdf . dgdsg dfg fgsdfsg fg dsfgsf sdfg</li>
  <li>abv asfbakjh dslsjdgljs lsgljgklj ljsdgll lslgklsdljlsdjgjksd lljljkj hghjgjhgjhgjhjg gjhghjsdf . dgdsg dfg fgsdfsg fg dsfgsf sdfg</li>

</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, i was trying to avoid using absolute position and tried this approach before with the same result, the li is messing the line heights. first line is too big in comparison with the following lines

Answer (score 3):

Try using `position:absolute;` for pseudo element and give `padding-left` to `<li>`

see updated snippet:

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
  /*columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  */
  width: 300px;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
  margin: 1rem 0.25rem;
  line-height: normal;
  padding-left: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

ol li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter);
  width: 44px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 24px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> test test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test test</li>
  <li> test test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test test</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your missing is you added counter in `pseudo` element but you expecting as like `ol li` default styling, although you reset the `ol` default behavior by adding `list-style: none;`. To work as expected you should follow below way:

```
ol {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
}
ol li {
    counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
    margin: 1rem 0.25rem;
    line-height: normal;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:45px;
    min-height:40px;
}
ol li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: counter(my-awesome-counter);
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 36px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid absolute positions but at the end I think there is no other way... thanks i'm gonna go for this approach

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the before's position absolute so that it will appear on the top of the list

I've attached two examples here:

1st one is the answer.

2nd one is why we should give position absolute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ol{width:250px;}
ol.a{
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin: 0;
  counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
  display:block;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type:none;
  }
ol.a li {
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
  display:block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ol.a li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 24px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
 }
 ol.b li:before{
     display: inline-block;
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 24px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  }



</style>
</head>
<body>
 <h2>With `postion:absolute`</h2>
<ol class="a">
  <li>Coffee - A brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, which are the seeds of berries from the Coffea plant</li>
   <li>Coffee - A brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, which are the seeds of berries from the Coffea plant</li>
   <li>Coffee - A brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, which are the seeds of berries from the Coffea plant</li>
</ol>
 <br><br>
<h2>Without `position:absolute`</h2>
   <ol class="b">
  <li>Coffee - A brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, which are the seeds of berries from the Coffea plant</li>
   <li>Coffee - A brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, which are the seeds of berries from the Coffea plant</li>
   <li>Coffee - A brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, which are the seeds of berries from the Coffea plant</li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

That's what happen when we don't position the before's position.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `display: flex` to the `ol li`.

Like this:

```
ol li {
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
  margin: 1rem 0.25rem;
  line-height: normal;
  display: flex;
}
```

Working demo here:
https://codepen.io/NightShade1993/pen/ReQWOb